# android error when select one image not multiple

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-gallery

I am trying to get images from my Gallery and upload them to the server. I want to allow the user to select multiple images from gallery. when I select two or more images it works very well. But when I select one image only it ignore it and return nothing. Here is my code and I am printing message when no clip Data is null

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if(data!=null)
            {
                ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();

                if (clipData != null) {
                    bitmaps_group=new Bitmap[clipData.getItemCount()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                        ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                        Uri uri = item.getUri();

                        try {
                            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
                            bitmaps_group[i]=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if(i==4)
                            i=clipData.getItemCount()+1;
                    }
                    new Encode_image().execute();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }

}
```

here where i call open the gallery:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        System.out.println("r1 clikcid");

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 10);
    }
});
```

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` Better: `Toast.makeText(getActivity(),data,getData().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If only one image is selected it will not be in `ClipData` as is the case with selecting more images.

Instead `data.getData()` will be the `Uri` of the selected one.

Comment: so how could i check the two cases?

Comment: Check them both to begin with. After that you will find the flow. Do you have that `"error"` toast now?

Comment: Do what you want. Its your app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is based on the API versions you targeting, try checking the build version before calling the intent so from:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 10);
```

change it to

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    try {
 Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 10);
 }catch(Exception e){
                        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(this, XYZ.class);
                        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                    }
                }
    else{
      Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(this, XYZ.class);
                        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: what do u mean by XYZ class? and why the API version will be problem while it is working for the multiple images selection

Comment: I use the XYZ to catch exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (requestCode == UPLOAD_GALLERY_REQ_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        if(data.getClipData()!=null){
         int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
         for(int i=0; i<count; i++){

             //here you can get your multiple images uri's
             // for example, i want array of selected images uri's so : 

             array.add(data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri());

         }
        }else {
         // and here you get the URI of single image (single selected)
            galleryUri.add(data.getData());
        }
```